# Why does my website only work in production if I set debug to true in the webconfig file?

Tags: asp.net

I built a pretty basic website in ASP.NET and tried uploading it to my hosting service (GoDaddy).  The page didn't load and instead I got a "This site can't be reached" error.  I spent several hours trying to figure out what was wrong, until I finally decided to just create a new WebForms project in VS 2013 and leave EVERYTHING as default (Ex: The website just says "Welcome to ASP.NET" and "Your Logo Here", etc.) and try to deploy that to the host.

Despite not changing ANYTHING, I still got a "Site can't be reached" error without any further details on what the issue was.  I added the line `<compilation debug="true"/>` to the web.config file and refreshed and the website displayed perfectly.

Why is this working fine in debug mode but not in production?

Comment: Did you contact GoDaddy support? Set the default page?

Comment: Yes I called them a few times which is what eventually led me to put "compilation debug = true"  They usually will only stay on the line until they determine the issue isnt on their end and then let you know it must be something wrong with the development

Comment: I was in process of migrating 21 ASP.NET Web Form sites to them from another host and eventually had to give up. The Plesk interface is draconian and the front line support guys are friendly but not savvy with ASPNET. Keep playing around with Plesk. One problem I had was that they had certain files in the root that caused problems. Other problems were with email, etc.

Comment: Thanks, i didn't realize there were these kinds of issues with godaddy.  it seems kind of crazy that it takes a lot of effort just to get a default template working in production